# specifying multiple functions at $(document).ready with UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am assigning an onclick event to all the textboxes in a GridView to show a calendar when clicked. The GridView is in an UpdatePanel. It only seems to work if you write it like this.

```
function InIEvent()
{
    $(".cal").click.function ()
    {
        showCalendar(this);
    });
}

$(document).ready(InIEvent);
```

Within an UpdatePanel that event will not be added to the textboxes without this further down the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(InIEvent);
</script>
```

My question is - how can I specify another function to also be called when the DOM is loaded? Let's say the GridView is in a Panel which is hidden while the page is loading and, when it is loaded, I want to call a function called showGrid() to change its display to block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(fucntion(){
InIevent();
showGrid();
});
```